# Trouble installing libflann1.7-dev on ubuntu

Tags: installation, apt, dependencies, libraries

I am trying to install libflann1.7-dev I have removed libflann1, so now I have no libflann at all. Next I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libflann1.7
```

which installed fine, I then try to install libflann1.7-dev and get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libflann1.7-dev : Depends: libflann1.7 (= 1.7.1-1+maverick5) but 1.7.1-4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have no idea why, as I have just installed libflann1.7 but apparently I have version 1.7.1.4 and libflann1.7-dev needs 1.7.1.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact I see a mention of `maverick` in there suggests to me that you have another repository in there. This usually happens when you have a crusty old PPA gumming things up with its own versions.

To double-check this I ran:

```
$ apt-cache depends libflann-dev 
libflann-dev
  Depends: libflann1.7
  Conflicts: libflann-dev:i386
```

No mention of a crusty maverick version :)

If you run `apt-cache policy libflann-dev` you will be able to see what versions are available to you, including which repos they're coming from. Spot the dodgy one and nuke it. In my case, here's what I see:

```
$ apt-cache policy libflann-dev 
libflann-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.7.1-4
  Version table:
     1.7.1-4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/universe amd64 Packages
```